# Batch file automating Windows HKCU Registry permissions using (SetACL)

Tags: windows, batch-file, inheritance, permissions, registry

I am working with our End User Computing team to automate our domain migrations. We are using a method that involves changing permissions (including "Replace permission entries on all child objects with entries shown here that apply to child objects") on the local user folder and HKCU in regedit.

I was able to automate most of the steps with a simple batch script. For the local folder permissions I used icacls:

```
icacls C:\Users\%localprofile% /grant %domainuser%@contoso.com:(OI)(CI)F /T
```

And for the registry I used SetACL:

```
"C:\Win7ProfileTool\SetACL\64 bit\SetACL.exe" -on "hkcu" -ot reg -actn ace -ace "n:%domainuser%@contoso.com;p:full"
"C:\Win7ProfileTool\SetACL\64 bit\SetACL.exe" -on "hkcu" -ot reg -actn setprot -op dacl:np;sacl:np
```

If I follow the method manually, it works without a problem. When I run my script I get an error about not loading the profile (and a temp created / booted).

I believe I have narrowed it down to my 2 SetACL lines, but I don't know exactly what parameters are needed to emulate "Replace permission entries on all child objects with entries shown here that apply to child objects."

My googlefu led me to an icacls solution that can't be used in RegEdit and I've been poking around on SetACL's help page (specifically the set-protection-flags, but I'm not sure of the ["protection"](https://helgeklein.com/setacl/documentation/command-line-version-setacl-exe/#protection) value)

Today I plan on taking a look into the Reset Children flag - but I'm not sure if I'm even on the right path.

**tl;dr** How do I emulate the Advanced Security tab checkbox ["Replace permission entries on..."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNZsD.png) via CMD using SetACL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running `setacl` over batch file to set registry and it works like a charm. Maybe the way you command causing trouble. The way I use (with admin privileges)

```
setacl.exe -on "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.%vfilext%\UserChoice" -ot reg -actn clear -clr dacl -silent
```

To be more specific and failproof. The version I use is 3.0.6 from [this page](https://helgeklein.com/setacl/documentation/command-line-version-setacl-exe/)